# Kotlin - Type mismatch required collection found list

Tags: android, kotlin

I need to append two `list` but it say me:

```
type mismatch required collection found list
```

It is like bellow:

```
val list: List<Cohort> = ArrayList()
private fun fillFromDao() {
    val notesObserver: Observer<ArrayList<Cohort?>?>? =
        Observer { cohort: ArrayList<Cohort?>? ->
                list.toMutableList().addAll(cohort)
        }
    if (notesObserver != null) {
        otherDialogFragmentViewModel.fetchIsFree()?.observe(this, notesObserver)
        otherDialogFragmentViewModel.fetchHasCertificate()?.observe(this, notesObserver)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two changes:

```
val list: List<Cohort?> = ArrayList()    ----> add '?' after Cohort
    private fun fillFromDao() {
        val notesObserver: Observer<ArrayList<Cohort?>?>? =
            Observer { cohort: ArrayList<Cohort?>? ->
                    list.toMutableList().addAll(cohort!!) ----> add '!!' after Cohort
            }
        if (notesObserver != null) {
            otherDialogFragmentViewModel.fetchIsFree()?.observe(this, notesObserver)
            otherDialogFragmentViewModel.fetchHasCertificate()?.observe(this, notesObserver)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Explain your answer please

Comment: Kotlin is a typesafe language, so type Cohort and Cohort? is a different types. And if you observe a list of Cohort? values, you need an apropriate container for them - so you need List<Cohort?>

Comment: For reference : create **ArrayList** `val list = ArrayList<CustomClass?>()` 
Check isNotEmpty   `if(it.response.data?.myList!!.isNotEmpty()) { 
list.addAll((it.response.data!!.myList!!)) 
}`

Answer (score 1):

`list` variable of type `List<Cohort>`, but `notesObserver` value type is `ArrayList<Cohort?>`: so `notesObserver` value can have *nullable* elements.

Thus either `list` variable should accept *nullable* or `notesObserver` should not have *nullable* values.